# Watch Networking Broken In Xcode 8 Beta 3

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I'm receiving the following error when sending any kind of http request from my WatchKit Extension:

```
WatchKit Extension[6128:479936] [WC] __33-[WCXPCManager onqueue_reconnect]_block_invoke error reconnecting to daemon due to NSXPCConnectionInterrupted
```

The message is only attempted to be sent if the session is reachable, which it is at this point. However when I inspect the session object I can see that while reachable is true and the activationState is 2 (WCSessionActivationStateActivated), other properties such as paired and watchAppInstalled are actually false.

In fact, the error is just repeatedly sent multiple times a second while I'm using the app in simulator or device. I'm not sure what's going on but I only started receiving this error when using Xcode 8 Beta 3.

App Delegate:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: NSError?) {
    if activationState == WCSessionActivationState.activated {
        NSLog("Activated")
    }

    if activationState == WCSessionActivationState.inactive {
        NSLog("Inactive")
    }

    if activationState == WCSessionActivationState.notActivated {
        NSLog("NotActivated")
    }
}

func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
    NSLog("sessionDidBecomeInactive")
}

func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
    NSLog("sessionDidDeactivate")

    // Begin the activation process for the new Apple Watch.
     WCSession.default().activate()
}
```

Extension Delegate:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    // Perform any final initialization of your application.

    if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        let session = WCSession.default()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
        print("activating")
    }

}

func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: NSError?) {
    // ...
}
```

Interface controller

```
if WCSession.defaultSession().reachable { // ... }
```

---

How can I solve, or at least work around this issue?

Comment: Beta 3 broke a few things.  Have you [filed a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) or posted on the [developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/beta/watchos-3-beta)?  Apple monitors their own site, but an Apple engineer might not see it here.

Comment: I actually don't know what's happening here.. If there have been some changes in watchkit implementation or is it really a bug?

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. I get back this multiple times per second while attempting to use WCSession communications between my WatchOS and iOS simulators:

`2016-07-28 13:00:42.962283 Watch Extension[75009:2496784] [WC] __33-[WCXPCManager onqueue_reconnect]_block_invoke error reconnecting to daemon due to NSXPCConnectionInterrupted`

Comment: Are you experiencing this on actual hardware or just in the simulator?

Comment: On b4, the excessive logging has disappeared for me but I still can't establish communication between iOS and watchOS simulators.

Comment: In Xcode 8.1 I get the same error on the simulator, when the `WCSession` is not reachable and I try to open system settings using `UIApplication.shared.open(URL.init(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`